# Ruby SecureRandom.hex producing only digits

Tags: ruby, random-seed

A quite weird situation.

I am generating random strings with `SecureRandom.hex(8)`, not in the same instance of code, intention is to have numbers and digits in the string.

Rarely it's output string like `757781121457` which should not be like this.

Rooting in source code of ruby 3.1.0 of `Random::Formatter` did not gave any response to this.

I was able to reproduce it with:

```rb
10000.times do |i|
  str = SecureRandom.hex(6)
  if str !~ /[a-z]/i || str !~ /[0-9]/
    p "Failed at #{i} with #{str}"
    raise StandardError.new
  end
end

"Failed at 207 with 757781121457"
```

It can fail even at try #20 :/

I have also tried `.alphanumeric` method but its does not fit because sometimes numbers are not included

Anyone have any clue why is so ?

Comment: What is wrong with `757781121457`? This is a perfectly valid hexadecimal number. If you have a requirement that there must be at least one letter, then you need to find a different way to generate your random strings.

Comment: By that logic, a random decimal number generator should not output `1010` because it's only binary digits?

Comment: Anyway, what's your expected result? What kind of strings do you want to generate? Or maybe explain what these strings are going to be used for (random password suggestions maybe?). Since you have `[a-z]` in your regex you seem to expect all letters of the alphabet, but hex only covers a-f.

Comment: I agree with all of you and already switched to own solution, but under what condition this tool generate ONLY numbers, this doesn't looks SecureRandom to me

Comment: @alexey_the_cat the output is _random_ which means that everything is possible. This includes results with only digits or only letters. It could even generate `12345678` or `deadbeef` because both are perfectly fine hexadecimal values. There's no specific condition though – it's random.

Answer (score 3):

> I am generating random strings with SecureRandom.hex(8), not in the same instance of code, intention is to have numbers and digits in the string.

You are using the wrong tool for the job both `ffffffff` and `00000000` are valid hexidecimal strings. As you saw, `757781121457` is valid as well. If you must have both letters and digits in the random string, you need to find a different method to generate them.